# Como pasar un array creado con Javascript e incluido en hidden a otro archivo PHP vía POST

Tags: php, javascript, post

He creado un array con javascript el cual he incluido en un hidden el cual estoy intentando pasar a otro archivo PHP (via POST) en otro campo hidden. Al pasarlo, simplemente se daña.

El paso a paso es el siguiente:

En Javascript hay una variable declarada

```
var listaProductosVenta = [];
```

La cual se llena de la siguiente manera

```
listaProductosVenta.push({"fechaVenta":tFechaVenta,
                  "codigo":tCodigo,
                  "tipo":tTipo,
                  "cantidad":tCantidad,
                  "prunitario":tprUnitario,
                  "prventa":tprVenta,
                  "total":tTotal,
                  "idMedicamento":tidMedicamento,
                  "registrosTotal":tregistrosTotal,
                  "consecutivo":tConsecutivo,
                  "usuario":tidUsuario});
```

NOTA: Las variables como tFechaVenta en realidad contienen otra información las cuál puede ser inventada si así se desea.

Luego, esta matriz se pasa al campo hidden mencionado en cual está en el Formulario 1 (Crear Venta), de la siguiente manera:

```
$("#listaProductosVenta").val(JSON.stringify(listaProductosVenta));
```

Esta matriz puede leida en un método POST cuando se envía directamente desde el formulario 1 (Crear venta). Sin embargo, cuando la intento enviar a otro formulario, ya no me funciona, el array luce igual, pero en realidad presenta un salto de línea.

Al otro formulario lo envío por el método POST de la siguiente manera:

```
<form role="form" method="post" class="formularioVenta" id="frmDataTableVenta" action="finalizar-venta">
```

Ya en el otro formulario (finalizar-venta), tomo el valor que viene del formulario anterior

```
<?php 
$listadoPr = $_POST["listaProductosVenta"]);
?>
```

Luego, lo paso al hidden

```
<input type="hidden" id="listaProductosVentaFinal" name="listaProductosVentaFinal" value = "<?php echo $listadoPr; ?>">
```

Comment: ¿El problema entonces cuál es en sí? Sí mal no recuerdo los campos hidden no son posteados con el formulario. Y me pregunto por qué no simplificas usando Ajax.

Comment: Cuando paso el array através del hidden, este no pasa bien a la segunda página. Mi conocimiento es limitado en estos tema, ¿Podría indicarme cómo lo hago por AJAX? Como paso el array y abro la segunda página para lea el array enviado??

Comment: Es que si usas Ajax ni siquiera necesitas abrir una segunda página, sino que puedes trabajar en la misma página, actualizando contenidos, mostrando u ocultando elementos, etc. Una de las ventajas de Ajax es que te permite realizar infinidad de operaciones sin la incomodidad de estar recargando páginas y páginas. Aquí hay varios ejemplos que indican cómo funciona Ajax, si te interesa hacerlo así podrías investigar y lanzarte por esa vía, te aseguro que no te vas a arrepentir.

Comment: Tiene toda la razón, tomé en cuenta su consejo y mucho más fácil. Muchas gracias